# USA Map with State Legislature Districts

Tags: united-states, data-sources, voting-districts, us-states

Is there a map with all state legislative voting districts? In other words, is there a single map which contains all of the districts which elect representatives to the lower state house, and a single map which contains one to the upper state house (often called the Senate).

Comment: Do you mean [congressional districts](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Congressional_district_maps_of_the_United_States#/media/File:US_Congressional_districts.svg)?

Comment: Do you mean state legislative districts?  Most state legislative chambers, with different numbers of seats.  Washington uses the same districts for both chambers, but most states' legislative districts do not line up between the chambers.  Most state legislative districts have nothing to do with the state's congressional districts.

Comment: I think he meant the electoral colleges.

Comment: Sry if it wasn't clear I meant state legislative districts @Era

Comment: I edited this question, and added information that will allow it to be hypothetically answerable. As noted in an existing answer there are two levels of state house. In order to be useful, there would need to be two maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found http://sunlightlabs.github.io/openstates-api/ which is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Link is dead... perhaps you can update it?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be practical to have a national map of all state legislative districts.  Not only do many states have two sets of different, overlapping districts, but the districts would often be too small to show on a national map.

Some of the relevant Wikipedia pages have maps.  E.g. for the [Arkansas House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkansas_House_of_Representatives):

[image: Arkansas House Districts 2012]

That's a high resolution image for one state and notice how some of the urban districts are difficult to see.  That only gets worse in more densely populated cities.  And then expand it out to a national map.  It's not practical.

Googling for "Alabama state senate districts" finds [this PDF](http://www.legislature.state.al.us/aliswww/Senate/2014_senate_districts.pdf).

The national census site has maps.  They look to be maps of each individual district:  https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/maps/reference-sld2014.html

It seems conceivable to compile the state maps into two national maps, one for the upper chambers and one for the lower chambers.  There would be some gaps as some state legislatures are unicameral (only one chamber).  But I don't see any sign that that has already been done.  And as I said, they wouldn't be particularly readable in urban areas.

Comment: I was looking for like a google map but I guess I'll just have to make one. Thanks for the advise and places to find the information though.